# Calling reactive objects into render output functions

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a dashboard in `Shiny`. I am taking inputs(data frame - `df1`) from a user and do some prediction and display the results of the prediction as well as a plot of air quality parameters.
Below is the `ui` code chunk -

```
########## User interface  ############
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Air Quality Index"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectizeInput(
      "City", "Select the City:", 
      choices = list("Mumbai", "Delhi", "Bengaluru") 
    ),
    numericInput("PM2.5", "PM2.5 Levels:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 50),
    numericInput("PM10", "PM10 Levels:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 50),
    numericInput("NO", "NO Levels:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 50),
    numericInput("CO", "CO Levels:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 50),
    numericInput("NO2", "NO2 Levels:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 50),
    numericInput("O3", "O3 Levels:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 50),
    actionButton("submitbutton", "Calculate AQI", class = "btn btn-primary")
  ),

dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    valueBoxOutput("AQI"),
    valueBoxOutput("high_risk_params")
    
  ),
  fluidRow(
    box(title = "Polluting Contents in Air:", solidHeader = TRUE,
        width = 12, collapsible = TRUE,
        plotlyOutput("param_plot"))
  )
))
```

And the code for `server` is -

```
########### Server logic ############
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Input Data
    datasetInput <-  reactive({
      df1 <- data.frame(
        Names=  c("City"= input$City, 
                  "PM2.5"= input$PM2.5,      
                  "PM10"= input$PM10,       
                  "NO"= input$NO,         
                  "NO2"= input$NO2,        
                  "CO"= input$CO,         
                  "O3"= input$O3        
        ),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
      
      n <- rownames(df1)
      input <- data.table::transpose(df1)
      colnames(input) <- n
      input[,2:7] <- as.numeric(input[,2:7])
      predicted <- data.frame(Predicted.AQI=predict(rf_model_new,input))
      print(predicted)
      
      
    })
      output$param_plot <- renderPlotly({
        
        df1 <- data.table::transpose(df1, keep.names = "rn")
        df1 <- df1[-1,]
        print(df1)
          plot <- ggplot(df1) + 
          geom_col(aes(x = rn, y = as.numeric(V1), fill = as.numeric(V1))) +
          labs(x = "Air Paramteres", y = "Value") + 
          theme_gray() + 
          ylim(0, NA) +
          geom_hline(yintercept = 50) +
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "green",
                              high = "red", 
                              limits = c(0, 300),
                              na.value = "darkred",
                              name = "Value") +
          theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "mintcream"), 
                legend.position = "none") 
        plot <- ggplotly(plot)
        plot
      })
      
      output$AQI <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(paste0( "AQI:  ",round(predicted,0)),
                " ", icon = icon("cloudscale"), color = "blue", width = 10)
      })
      
      output$high_risk_params <- renderValueBox({
        
        risk_df <- df1 %>%
          filter(df1[,2:7]> 100)
      if(nrow(risk_df)>0){
        valueBox("Over Safe Limits", HTML(paste0(risk_df$rn, sep= "<br>")), 
                 icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"), color = "red")
      }
        else{
          valueBox("No Hazard", icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"), color = "green")
        }
      })
    
    
    
}
```

Now the error showing is -
`Warning: Error in data.table::transpose: object 'df1' not found` &
`Warning: Error in paste0: object 'predicted' not found` &
`Warning: Error in filter: object 'df1' not found`

Attaching screenshot of the errors.
Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ncQq.png

Comment: It's unclear what you are doing with `datasetInput`. You don't seem to use that reactive value anywhere. But since you are creating the `df1` variable only inside the `datasetInput` reactive object, that's the only place it's available. That variable will never leave that scope. Maybe check out these videos on reactivity to see how shiny is meant to be used: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick I'll check

Answer (score 0):

try to declare df1 var outside the reactive({}) function and make it global across the whole server and then use it below inside the renderPlotly({}) function

Comment: I am not sure that can work. `df1` depends on user input and needs to be changed reactively. Rather create a reactive expression that returns this data frame.

Comment: I tried to run this code on my machine and I found a lot of errors related to the declaration of the variables not only `df1` a lot of other variables too, I think the logic of the code should be reimplemented from scratch to fix all of this bugs